# Jasmine Spy Undefined

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

When I run my jasmine specs I get the following error:

```
Error: Expected a spy, but got undefined.
```

My coffeescript code:

```
  describe "setupForm", ->
    beforeEach ->
      spyOn(Subscription.prototype, 'runSimulation')

    it "calls subscription.runSimulation when form is submitted with number", ->
      Subscription.prototype.runSimulation()
      expect(Subscription.prototype.runSimulation()).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

I have simplfied my erroring code to the above for debugging, but I can't figure out why it is saying the spy is never called when I'm explicitly calling it my test. I am testing the method in other places, so I think the error has to be with how I am using the Jasmine Spy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take the `()` off the end of `Subscription.prototype.runSimulation()`:

```
  expect(Subscription.prototype.runSimulation).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: If you pass `Subscription.prototype.runSimulation()`, you're actually passing the *return value* of the function, not the function itself. The return value (I assume) is undefined, which is why you were getting that error.

Comment: Incidentally, you were also running the simulation twice (once in the first line of the `it` block, once in the second line where you passed its return value to `expect`).

Comment: @shioyama comment should be part of the answer, the why is always of greater use than the how :-)